# Detach quote from customer session

Tags: catalog, session, customer

I need to somehow detach the quote from the customer session so it is still sitting in the DB marked as active but no longer part of the customer session (still with the customer_id in the DB record though).  I've been scouring all the customer session and quote code but can't see anything obvious that helps me implement this.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what are you trying to do? Quotes are detached from the customer sessions: they outlive sessions and can also be created via api when there is no customer session present. Let us know what are you trying to achieve so we can point you to the right way to do it.

Comment: Basically, I have  a system where logged in customers can change which customer they are logged in as by selecting a new customer from a dropdown.  This does not destroy the customer session as they have to be logged in to be able to switch the customer they are logged in as.  So, if I switch customer in the session I need to be able to lay aside the cart items so if they switch back to the previous customer record their cart will be regenerated.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, they have different identities with the same `customer_id`? Having different IDs would solve your problem perfectly, then you just change the customer in the session: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/sharing-cart-between-customers/1165#1165

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to reset the current customer's quote to a blank quote (e.g. to 'save' their cart for later) the following should suffice (untested code):

To change the current quote:

```
$quote_id = /*your quote id here*/ ;
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId($quote_id);
```

To get rid of the current quote altogether:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId(null);
```

**Edit**

If you want to forcefully reattach a customer's quote to another customer, you can change the `customer_id` of the `sales_flat_quote` field:

*For registered customers*:

`$quote->setCustomerId($customer_id);`

*For guests*:

```
$quote->setCustomerId(null)
    ->setCustomerEmail($email)
    ->setCustomerFirstname($firstname)
    ->setCustomerLastname($lastname)
    ->save();
$quote_id = $quote->getId();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId($quote_id);
```

Comment: Hmm possibly that may work, was thinking along the same lines just now.  I'll give that a go and see if it works.

Comment: Let me know. I'll keep digging as well.

Comment: It certainly works up to a point and I can retrieve the quote_id using    `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->loadCustomerQuote()->getQuoteId()` but it doesn't seem to reattach when I set the quoteId in the checkout session.  Must be nearly there though.

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId(null); is not working any idea?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to quickly do this for a customer - and with a non-programatic solution, you can just replace the `quote_id` for the items in the old quote.

Eg.

UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` 
   SET quote_id = '**NEW_QUOTE_ID**' 
   WHERE quote_id = '**OLD/EXISTING_QUOTE_ID**'

*Replace `__NEW_QUOTE_ID__` and `__OLD/EXISTING_QUOTE_ID__` as necessary*